# Cheapest way to get to Westminster from Downtown LA?

Tags: public-transport, transportation, california, los-angeles

I'd like some suggestions on how to cheaply get from Downtown LA (around the Financial District, Union station...area) to Westminster in OC, CA (specifically the Little Saigon Market area there) cheaply. I hope to be able to leave early in the morning (between 6:00am - 8:30am) and return at around noon on the same day.

I have considered taking an Uber, which will cost me between $42 and $55 and will take me roughly 1hr, but would like some alternatives. I haven't really found any good bus routes yet, and as far as I'm aware the LA metro does not go sufficiently far from downtown LA to be able to get near Westminster to make it worthwhile to book a short car trip afterwards there (e.g. I don't think it goes as far as Garden Grove, which if it did would allow me to then take a short car trip to Westminster).

EDIT: This is a three person round trip, so it would help if the total cost of transporting all three people is considered.

Comment: Weekday or Weekend?

Comment: @Crazydre Saturday, so weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the *cheapest* way, but the quickest route will definitely be cheaper than Uber.

1. Take the Amtrak Pacific Surfliner Train from Union Station (at 6:05AM or 7:25AM, costing $17 if booked [online](https://tickets.amtrak.com) in advance) to Santa Ana.
2. Walk to the bus stop 1st-Standard as shown [here](https://www.google.ch/maps/dir/Santa+Ana+Regional+Transportation+Center,+1000+E+Santa+Ana+Blvd,+Santa+Ana,+CA+92701,+USA/1st-Standard,+Santa+Ana,+Kalifornien,+USA/@33.7483193,-117.8586085,17z/data=!4m19!4m18!1m10!1m1!1s0x80dcd9a079937a29:0xa10de874d4b19261!2m2!1d-117.8564734!2d33.7516133!3m4!1m2!1d-117.8569399!2d33.7468118!3s0x80dcd90c8505c5bd:0xbcc09d1272836b8!1m5!1m1!1s0x80dcd90cf5a28cbd:0x6a09c79831671757!2m2!1d-117.85742!2d33.74565!3e2)
3. Take bus 64 to Little Saigon (ask the driver to let you off at the correct stop).

Same thing on the way back (get off bus 64 at 1st-Standard for Santa Ana station), although if you take the Metrolink commuter Train (timetable [here](http://www.metrolinktrains.com/schedules/stationtostation/?from=125&to=131&weekday=0&submit.x=47&submit.y=4)) rather than the Pacific Surfliner it costs almost half the Price. That one doesn't need to be booked online, as the price is fixed.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a three person trip, so I'll have to take into account 3 tickets for the Amtrak Pacific Surfliner Train, as well as for the bus 64 to Little Saigon. I presume the $17 ticket is per person. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @user98937 Correct. In that case Uber might be cheaper after all. Not on the way back though thanks to Metrolink